# Make WebStorm see the paths

Tags: reactjs, electron, webstorm

I do have an Electron + React project which I inherited from another developer.
in the index.js there are a couple of imports that WebStorm is saying it cannot find, however, the application compiles and works as needed.

[image]

and here is the structure of the folders relative to `index.js`

[image]

How do I make WebStorm happy and make it see the imports and navigate properly to them?
I tried to use `exports` section in the `package.json` like this

```
"exports": {
    "./": "./src/"
  }
```

but it didn't help.
Any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on *src* directory and select *Mark Directory as | Resource Root*.